# Comparing multiple columns of same CSV file and returning result to another CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file with 7 columns

This is my csv file

```
Application,Expected Value,ADER,UGOM,PRD
APP,CVD2,CVD2,CVD2,CVD2
APP1,"VCF7,hg6","VCF7,hg6","VCF8,hg6","VCF7,hg6"
APP1,"VDF9,pova8","VDF9,pova8","VDF10,pova10","VDF9,pova11"
APP2,gf8,gf8,gf8,gf8
APP3,pf8,pf8,gf8,pf8
APP4,vd3,mn7","vd3,mn7","vd3,mn7","vd3,mn7"
```

So here i want to compare a **Expected Value** column  with the columns after that **(that is ADER,UGOM,PRD)**

so here is my code in python

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    # assuming id columns are identical and contain the same values
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', index_col='Expected Value')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', index_col='ADER')
    
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['status'], index=df1.index)
    df3['status'] = (df1['Expected Value'] == df2['ADER']).replace([True, False], ['Matching', 'Not Matching'])
    
    df3.to_csv('output.csv')
```

So this not creating any `output.csv` file ,nor it generates any output . So can anyone help

**So i edited code : based on a comment by @Vlado**

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming id columns are identical and contain the same values
df1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Application','Expected Value','ADER','status of AdER'], index=df1.index)
df3['Application']  = df1['Application']
df3['Expected Value']  = df1['Expected Value']
df3['ADER']  = df1['ADER']

df3['status'] = (df1['Expected Value'] == df1['ADER'])

df3['status'].replace([True, False], ['Matching', 'Not Matching'])
df3.to_csv('output.csv')
```

so now it works for one column ADER , but my headers after EXpected Values are dynamic , it may change . so sometimes it may be one column after expected Value , sometimes N columns and header name may also change . so can some one help on how to do that

Comment: i tried that too , but it was not working @RichieV

Comment: No , it shows different one

Comment: it is understandable that in the course of solving the problem you find out that you have more and different complications along the way, even so, the best way to get good answers is to have a clear understanding of what you want to fix in your code before posting a question... otherwise some answers are no longer relevant and yet those users spent time to help you out... if you find that this strays much from the original post please search for old questions that can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below given piece of code generates the desired output. It will compare the Expected Value column with rest of the columns after that.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

expected_value_index = df.columns.get_loc("Expected Value")
for col_index in range(expected_value_index+1, len(df.columns)):
    column = df.columns[expected_value_index]+" & "+ df.columns[col_index]
    df[column] = df.loc[:,"Expected Value"] == df.iloc[:,col_index]
    df[column].replace([True, False], ["Matching", "No Matching"], inplace=True)

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=None)
```

Comment: yeah , but the thing is , i not just want to compare the Expected Value to ADER , but also i want to compare to other columns to . so here  the columns are dynamic it may be one or two or many . so i want to compare Expected value to all the column that are coming after Expected Value column @Hamza Sabir

Comment: @neerajasreelaxmi i have updated the code as your desired result. Now, Expected Value will be compared with rest of the columns after that dynamically.

Comment: yeah this works fine but instead of creating a separate column is there any way so that i can keep all non-matching columns as red

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried replicating your code as of yet but here are a few suggestions:

You do not need to read the df two times.
df1 = pd.read_csv('FinalResult1.csv')
is sufficient.

Then, you can proceed with

df1['status'] = (df1['exp'] == df1['ader'])

df1['status'].replace([True, False], ['Matching', 'Not Matching'])

Alternatively, you could do this row by row by using the pandas apply method.
If that doesn't work a reasonable first step would be to print your dataframe out to see what is happening.

Comment: am very new to this dataframe concept of python , so can you explain me how to do pandas.apply function  @Vlado

Comment: and i want to apply this to every column that comes after **Expected Value**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
k = list(df1.columns).index('Expected Value') + 1
    # get the integer index for the column after 'Expected Value'
df3 = df1.iloc[:, :k]
    # copy first k columns
df3 = pd.concat([df3, (df1.iloc[:, k:] == np.repeat(
    df1['Expected Value'].to_frame().values, df1.shape[1] - k, axis=1))], axis=1)
    # slice df1 with iloc, wich works just as slicing lists in python
    # np.repeat, used to repeat 'Expected Value' as many columns as needed (df1.shape[1]-k=3)
    # .to_frame, slicing a column from a df returns a 1D series so we turin it back into a 2D df
    # .values, returns the underlying numpy array without any index/column names
        # ...without .values Pandas would try to find 3 columns named 'Expected Value' in df1
    # concatenate previous df3 with this calculation
print(df3)
```

Output

```
  Application   FileName   ConfigVariable Expected Value  ADER   UGOM    PRD
0        APP1  FileName1  ConfigVariable1           CVD2  True   True   True
1        APP1  FileName2  ConfigVariable2       VCF7,hg6  True  False   True
2        APP1  FileName3  ConfigVariable3     VDF9,pova8  True  False  False
3        APP2  FileName4  ConfigVariable4            gf8  True   True   True
4        APP3  FileName5  ConfigVariable5            pf8  True  False   True
5        APP4  FileName6   ConfigVariable        vd3,mn7  True   True   True
```

Of course you can do a loop if for some reason you need a special calculation on some column

```
for colname in df1.columns[k:]:
    df3[colname] = df1[colname] == df1['Expected Value']
```